# Smart Capture Form and Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpage, form

I have to create a Journey using as "entry source" a Salesforce Campaign, and sending an email with a link to a SMART CAPTURE FORM.

After a "Wait" period, I need to split between people who submitted the form and not.
How can I split this? May I use an engagement o decision split?

Comment: You will need a decision split, but that's not the challenging part. You will need to process your data, and connect it in a Data Designer attribute group, to evaluate the criteria properly.

Comment: Good idea. As a beginner user, I found a less complicated way for now: making a second journey and using as entry source CloudPages and the smart capture form, so I take data from the first customer journey into the second one